Dimension error using sparse.block_diag in Python
I am trying to make a block diagonal matrix using the function:
 mo = sparse.block_diag([np.exp(-1j*A)*np.cos(A),
                                     *[B for _ in range(int(N/2-1))],
                                     np.exp(-1j*A)*np.cos(A)])

where B is a 2x2 matrix and A is a number. Somehow this errors, saying:
all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
How can I fix this?
Previously this worked for other numbers, but I am not sure why it is not working now.

Is this code based on numpy? If so, add an according tag for better visibility. Also, please provide a [mcve] and not just the snippet of code that you think is the cause of the error. This just isn't enough context. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Somehow the answer was in the definition of the B matrices: using np.matrix didn't work and using np.array it did.
